Expectation of Ratio of Gaussian Mixed Moments
Suppose $X\sim N(0, \sigma_x^2)$ and $Y\sim N(0, \sigma_y^2)$ are dependent. How can we deal with ratios of mixed moments of $X$ and $Y$? The main expression we have is:
$E[\frac{(1+X^2)(XY)}{(1+X^2)^2 + (XY)^2}] \quad\geq\quad  \dots$
This expectation is zero whenever $X$ and $Y$ are independent due to the whole expression being odd in both. However, whenever $X$ and $Y$ are positively correlated, this should be bounded away from zero. It seems, at least for this specific instance, we could define auxiliary random variables $A=1+X^2$ and $B=XY$ to try to lower bound the expectation:
$E[\frac{AB}{A^2+B^2}]\quad\geq\quad\dots$
but neither avenue has really yielded anything useful. Any help or even a bump in the right direction would be very valuable; thank you!
